# vaex: How to limit number of cores/threads/processes?

Tags: python-3.x, bigdata, vaex

How can one limit the number of cores/threads/processes that are being used by `vaex`? Some operations have a boolean `parallel` switch, but I don't see a way to have more fine-grained control (which is important on larger shared servers).

Code snippet at hand:

```py
vaex.open("/very/large/file.parquet/")\
   .sample(frac=0.01)\
   .export_parquet("/slightly/smaller/file.parquet", parallel=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the number of threads, you can use a env variable named `VAEX_NUM_THREADS`, by default it uses `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`

cf https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/blob/2418d56a1925a82557a8e86493f5e5d117c06049/packages/vaex-core/vaex/multithreading.py#L21